# What is an appropriate value for git-daemon's --timeout option?

Tags: git

The `git-daemon` page has this to say:

```
   --init-timeout=<n>
       Timeout (in seconds) between the moment the connection is established
       and the client request is received (typically a rather low value,
       since that should be basically immediate).

   --timeout=<n>
       Timeout (in seconds) for specific client sub-requests. This includes
       the time it takes for the server to process the sub-request and the
       time spent waiting for the next client's request.
```

I feel relatively comfortable setting `--init-timeout` to something like 30s, seeing as the man page says "typically a rather low value", but I could use some guidance for what is a reasonable value of `--timeout`, seeing as it says it "includes the time it takes for the server to process the sub-request", which seems like it could be quite a long time.

I'm currently trying out a value of 600s (10 minutes).

*(Repost of [previous question deleted due to inactivty](https://superuser.com/questions/1160507/what-is-an-appropriate-value-for-git-daemons-timeout-option)).*

Comment: Just to say, you can *totally* flag an old question for undeletion, especially if you know where it is, was roombaed and you can answer it. At this point though, having a proper question/answer pair is more valuable so I'll undelete that and close it as a dupe of this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I did click the "undelete" link, but that only allowed me to "vote" for it to be undeleted, and there was no way to provide an undeletion reason, so I figured it wasn't going to have any effect. Thanks for cleaning up the dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally asked this question in December 2016 but it got deleted due to inactivity. Having trialled my suggested values (`--init-timeout` of `30` and `--timeout` of `600`) since then (ie. 21 months at the time of writing), I can report that the values are appropriate:

- I have had no reports of service exhaustion (port being monopolized by a hung process).
- I have had no reports of the timeouts being too aggressive (ie. preventing legitimate connection and operation attempts from proceeding).